# Comma delimited import issues in SQL Server

Tags: csv, sql-server, import

I am having a problem with SQL Server. I have a table with 42 columns to which there is frequent monthly imports. These imports are from a flat file using the import and export wizard. My problem is that my location column has information in the format:

- Sydney, Australia
- London, England
- Paris, France
- New York City, USA

What is the best way for me to display the data the same way or similiarly without the location column being split in two. For example: could i put quotes around everything? I know you can just check, but is there sometype of control that i could implelement that would prompt an error if somethig like this happens?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [rfc4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), you must use double quotes to enclose the field.

> Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
> should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:

```
   "aaa","b CRLF
   bb","ccc" CRLF
   zzz,yyy,xxx
   "New York City, USA","next field value","Field, With, Lots, Of, Commas"
```

Comment: @Techie007, Thanks that does make the example more clear for this situation. I was torn between adding an example to be more clear, and my instinct to not modify the quote.